# Time limitation exceeded in Java compared to Python on the exact same code

Tags: java, python, performance, optimization

The following code I wrote in JAVA takes more than  2 seconds to execute in some absurd test cases:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= sc.nextLong();
    long a[]= new long[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  // Input.
    {
        a[i]= sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)  // Sorting(descending order).
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<a[j+1])
            {
                long t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }

    int k=1;
    long max=a[0];

    while(k<=n-1)   // Comparing
    {
        long k1=a[k]*(k+1);
        
        if(max<k1)
        {
            max=k1;
        }

        k++;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
    sc.close();
}
}
```

But the same code written in Python takes less:

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    l.append(int(input()))
l.sort(reverse=True)
k=1;
max=l[0]
while(k<n):
    k1=l[k]*(k+1)
    if(max<k1):
        max=k1
    k=k+1
print(max)
```

**Why?**
[Results after executing the JAVA code in CodeChef](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9pAo.jpg)

I cannot review the Test cases which have failed.

Comment: Why use long array if you are just going to store int?

Comment: What is this code? seems like doing bubble sort.

Comment: This might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: @GoionI Just changed it.

Comment: Yes but you waste 32 bits space since it won't be utilized. Also, I am not sure what the loop in second half doing.

Comment: @Goion http://codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/ZCO14003 This is the question, there is an execution time limit of 2 sec.

Comment: can you please add it in the question itself. It will definitely help all the users want to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in java and python implementations:
In java you wrote some kind of a bubble sort with complexity `O(n^2)`, here it is:

```java
   for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)  // Sorting(descending order).
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<a[j+1])
            {
                long t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
```

And in python you are using built-in `sort` method, which I think, has complexity of `O(n*logn)`

```
l.sort(reverse=True)
```

That is the reason for time difference. If you'll use `Arrays.sort()` in java, it probably will fix the problem.

Comment: Just for info: Python sort uses TimSort and Java sort uses Dual-Pivot Quicksort

Comment: Another note: `Arrays.sort()` in Java can perform in O(n^2) in some cases.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I didn't realise that bubble sort was so damn slow.